# Gesture in ios7 not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, gesture

I make a custom view name "Cus_TextEdit" using UIView.
File Cus_TextEdit.m

```
    @implementation Cus_TextView
    @synthesize text;
    - (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame textNew:(NSString*)textNew {
          self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
          if (self) {
                [self setText:textNew];
                 UIColor* bg = [UIColor colorWithRed:225 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
                 self.backgroundColor = bg;
          }
         return self;

      }
   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
        self.text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(5, 0) withFont:[myFont];
    }
```

In file ViewControler.h i make :

```
   @property (retain, nonatomic) UIPanGestureRecognizer* panGestureRecognizer;

   - (IBAction)clickBtn:(id)sender;
```

When i click a button on main view , function clickBtn will called with code(in file ViewController.m):

```
    Cus_TextView* cus_tv = [[Cus_TextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50) textNew:@"Hello"];
        [cus_tv setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        UIPanGestureRecognizer* panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureRecognizer)];
        [cus_tv addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
        [self.view addSubview:cus_tv];
```

Implement function panGestureRecognizer

```
     -(void) panGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) gesture {
          NSLog(@"panGestureRecognizer called");
          CGPoint newPoint = [gesture locationInView:[self view]];
         [[gesture view] setCenter:newPoint];
      }
```

When i run app,click button, text "Hello" displayed. But when i click it, panGestureRecognizer function not be call.

Answer (score 4):

You have missed `:` in target method`(panGestureRecognizer:)`. Just Use this..

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureRecognizer:)];
```